# Web3J - how to perform two identical transactions in a row?

Tags: web3j

I have a contract being an ERC-20 token. I want to perform two idendical transfers (sender, receiver and amounts are the same).

I am using the contract objects from Web3j:

```
MyToken token = MyToken.load(tokenAddress, web3j, credentials, DefaultGasProvider()));
token.transfer(recipient, amount).send();
token.transfer(recipient, amount).send();
```

However, the secont transaction fails with "Known transaction" error. How can I make this work and successfully perform two distinct, but identical transactions?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I think you have to use [FastRawTransactionManager](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/web3j/tx/FastRawTransactionManager.java). It will cache the previous nonce and increment with a new transaction.

Comment: Helped. Unfortunately it is not possible to do it using the generated contract classes - I needed to create and send raw transactions on my own. Thank you! :)